# Python Beginner: How can I make text #1 look like text #2

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a loop that will format, space, and align the 1st text to match the 2nd text. I am inputting text 1 from a txt file and I want it to output text 2 into a txt file. The syntax should print text #2 with the 3rd column summed.

Text #1

```
$1120.47 $944.42
$72.29 $588.23
$371.21 $2183.84
```

Text #2

```
$ 1120.47  $  944.42  $ 2064.89
$   72.29  $  588.23  $  660.52
$  371.21  $ 2183.84  $ 2555.05
```

This is what I have so far...you can tell this is only my 2nd week writing python.:) Any help would be appreciated.

```
inputfilename= input('Enter sales file name: ')
outputfilename=input('Enter name for total sales file: ')

infile=open(inputfilename, "r")
outfile=open(outputfilename, "w")

salessequence=infile.readlines()

for sale in salessequence:
    splitsale=sale.strip().split(" ")
    firstsale=splitsale[0]
    lastsale=splitsale[1]
    dollarsign1=firstsale[0:1]
    firstsale2=firstsale[1:]
    lastsale2=lastsale[1:]
    total=firstsale2 + lastsale2
    print(total, file=outfile)

infile.close()
outfile.close()

print('All finished')
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10623727/5787099 might be able to give you some good information

Answer (score 0):

Three things to correct in your attempt:

1. Use the string method `rjust` (right-justify) to align columns. It adds extra spaces to the start of a string.
2. Always close a file after reading writing is complete. Alternatively use the with syntax (see code example below) as it automatically closes the file after exiting the with block.
3. Use `file.write` to write lines to a file
4. look at the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) & [pandas library](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) as they provide advanced data & file handling techniques.

example code to read from a file & write to a new file:

```
inputfilename= input('Enter sales file name: ')
outputfilename=input('Enter name for total sales file: ')

with open(inputfilename, 'r') as i, open(outputfilename, 'w') as o:
    for line in i:
        fst_sale, lst_sale = line.split(' ')
        fst_sale = float(fst_sale[1:])
        lst_sale = float(lst_sale[1:])
        tot_sale = fst_sale + lst_sale
        new_line = ''.join(
            ['$' + str(x).rjust(10) 
            for x in [fst_sale, lst_sale, tot_sale]]
        )
        o.write(new_line + '\n')
```

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful! One question, when I try to run the example code I get this error. fst_sale, lst_sale = line.split(' ')
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: What is the best way to resolve the following error?                     
               fst_sale, lst_sale = line.split(' ')
               ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: that error means that your file has a line that doesn't have a space. try `'abc def'.split(' ')`. it should output `['abc', 'def']`. now try 'abcdef'.split(' ') in the console. this will output `['abcdef']`