# Print format with the same spacing

Tags: python

I want to have output with the same spacing. Let me illustrate desired output:

```
Item1 = 1000 USD
Item2 = 500  USD
Item3 = 1500 USD
```

My current code:

```
print("{:4s} = {} {}" .format(name, round(value), currency))
```

My current output has very ugly second item output

```
Item1 = 1000 USD
Item2 = 500 USD
Item3 = 1500 USD
```

The problem is that for the second variable I cannot fix the spacing it consumes unlike the string in first variable.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623727/python-spacing-and-aligning-strings) helping you?

Comment: Why can't you fix the second value the same way you fixed the first?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your suggestion. My final code is below - work as expected.

```
print(f"{asset_name:<6}" + ' = ' + f"{round(asset_value,2):<7}" + '  ' + f"{qoute_currency:<3}")
```

Comment: Why are you concatenating multiple strings?

Comment: I do not know a better way. If you have any suggestion, kindly show example.