# Need help in aligning the content in python for self automation

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to create an anime series search using the tool anilistpython, but I am not able to ignore the newline character in the plot tag and need help in align the output in a proper view format.

Tried code :

```
from AnilistPython import Anilist
import pandas as pd
import re

# db access online
anilist = Anilist()

# User input
ani_search = anilist.get_anime(input('Enter the Anime Name\t:\t'), manual_select=True)
df = ani_search

# for Genres split
cate = []
for gen in df['genres']:
    cate.append(gen)
    cate1 = (' , '.join(cate))

# for Checking Episode
if df['airing_status'] == 'RELEASING':
    print('Ongoing')
    x ='Ongoing'
    y = df['next_airing_ep']
    print(y['episode'])
    y1 = y['episode']
elif df['airing_status'] == 'FINISHED':
    print('Ended')
    x = 'Ended'
    y = df['airing_episodes']
    print(y)
    y1 = y
else:
    print('None')

# print other details

print(f"\nTitle_Name\t:\t{df['name_english']}\nRomji_Title\t:\t{df['name_romaji']}\nPlot\t:\t{re.split('<br>', df['desc'])}\nAiring_Format\t:\t{df['airing_format']}\nStatus\t:\t{x}\nEpisodes_Count\t:\t{y1}\nGenres\t:\t{cate1}\nRating\t:\t{df['average_score']}/100\n")
```

The output it generated :

```
Enter the Anime Name    :   Bleach
1. BLEACH
2. BEACH
3. Akkanbee da
Please select the anime that you are searching for in number: 1

Title_Name  :   Bleach
Romji_Title :   BLEACH
Plot    :   ["Ichigo Kurosaki is a rather normal high school student apart from the fact he has the ability to see ghosts. This ability never impacted his life in a major way until the day he encounters the Shinigami Kuchiki Rukia, who saves him and his family's lives from a Hollow, a corrupt spirit that devours human souls. \n", '', '\nWounded during the fight against the Hollow, Rukia chooses the only option available to defeat the monster and passes her Shinigami powers to Ichigo. Now forced to act as a substitute until Rukia recovers, Ichigo hunts down the Hollows that plague his town. \n\n\n']
Airing_Format   :   TV
Status  :   Ended
Episodes_Count  :   366
Genres  :   Action , Adventure , Supernatural
Rating  :   76/100
```

I am looking for the format to look like this:

```
Title_Name     :    Bleach
Romji_Title    :    BLEACH
Plot           :    Ichigo Kurosaki is a rather normal high school student apart from the fact he has the ability to see ghosts. This ability never impacted his life in a major way until the day he encounters the Shinigami Kuchiki Rukia, who saves him and his family's lives from a Hollow, a corrupt spirit that devours human souls. Wounded during the fight against the Hollow, Rukia chooses the only option available to defeat the monster and passes her Shinigami powers to Ichigo. Now forced to act as a substitute until Rukia recovers, Ichigo hunts down the Hollows that plague his town.
Airing_Format  :    TV
Status         :    Ended
Episodes_Count :    366
Genres         :    Action , Adventure , Supernatural
Rating         :    76/100
```

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10623851/4440387

Comment: Also this official doc: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec