# How to format to a string to a fixed length which stores in a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

I have a number and I want to format to a string with zero padding and a specific length . Suppose if the fixed length is 22 , I know I can do in this way

```
 format(variable,"%022d")
```

but does there exist any way can do by this

```
length = 22
format(variable,"%0lengthd")
```

It means I need to use variable in `% variable d` expression

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`str(variable).zfill(length)`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill) for this:

```
>>> str(12345).zfill(8)
'00012345'
>>> str(12345).zfill(10)
'0000012345'
```

It might seem somewhat unintuitive to have to convert the number to a string before zero-padding it, but (at least in my opinion) this is much cleaner than using multiple formats. After all, why hack together a solution when it's already builtin?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, by using string formatting inside:

```
length = 22
format(variable,"%0{}d".format(length))
```

Infact, you could probably do this whole thing with one call of [`str.format()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
length = 22
"{0:{1}}".format(variable, length)
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

Even classic string interpolation supports this:

```
>>> variable = 100
>>> length = 22
>>> print "%0*d" % (length,variable)
0000000000000000000100
```

See more details at this answer: [variable length of %s with the % operator in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448820/variable-length-of-s-with-the-operator-in-python/1448834#1448834)