# Print dynamically based on length of string

Tags: python, loops

I am a newbie to Python and trying to use print and for loop to print a pattern like following, where the width of block depends on the characters I want to enter, i.e. width of block and surrounding lines increase dynamically with length of string say, ABCDEFGHI.. :

```
┏━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃  ABCDE   ┃
┗━━━━━━━━━━┛
```

I am trying to iterate over the characters of string like -

```
name = "abcdefghi"

for i in name:
    print("━",end="")

print()

for j in range(1):
    print("┃"+" "*(len(name)-1)+"┃")

for k in name:
    print("━",end="")
```

which gives me an output like,

```
━━━━━━━━━━━━
┃           ┃
━━━━━━━━━━━━
```

1. How can I use multiple loops to END the lines? (such that the pattern does not look like an open-ended box)
2. Is there someway I can start the second loop index -1 than the line `━━━` pattern?

Need suggestions on what to try?

Comment: Are you trying to just put the name in the box like the first example?

Comment: The problem is with the characters you are printing, not the loops. I suggest you find the corner characters in order to print what you want.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20756516/python-create-a-text-border-with-dynamic-size

Answer (score 5):

There are characters like `'┏'` in your sample so you need to consider them while designing your logic:

```
name = "abcdefghi"
width = len(name) + 4
print('┏' + "━"*width + "┓")
print('┃' + name.center(width) + '┃')
print('┗' + "━"*width + "┛")
```

```
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃  abcdefghi  ┃
┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛
```

Answer (score 2):

You can first built the complete string and then print it

```py
name = "abcdefghi"

hh = (len(name)+4)*"━" # horizontal line, using "string multiplication"
box = f"┏{hh}┓\n┃  {name}  ┃\n┗{hh}┛" # using f-string substitution
print(box)
```

```
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃  abcdefghi  ┃
┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write the name in a box, then you do not need the `for` loops. You can use `"━" * len(name)` for the variable length string in the way that your existing code is using `" "*(len(name)-1)`

```
name = "abcdefghi"

print("┏━" + "━" * len(name) + "━┓")
print("┃ " + name + " ┃")
print("┗━" + "━" * len(name) + "━┛")
```

giving:

```
┏━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ abcdefghi ┃
┗━━━━━━━━━━━┛
```

And for a slightly wider box as in the question, it is probably easiest just to hard-code some slightly longer strings at the edges:

```
print("┏━━" + "━" * len(name) + "━━┓")
print("┃  " + name + "  ┃")
print("┗━━" + "━" * len(name) + "━━┛")
```

giving:

```
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃  abcdefghi  ┃
┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛
```